# How to find which integral has a larger (real) area?

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-numbers

So I decided to compare integrals to see which ones had a larger area. After a while, I came up with this question:$$\text{Which integral has a greater area: }\mathfrak{Re}\left(\int_Df(x,y)dxdy\right)\text{ or }\mathfrak{Re}\left(\int_0^1(-1)^{\ln(x)}dx\right)\text{?}$$where$$f(x,y):=(-1)^{\operatorname{Ln}(xy)},D=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2,0\le x\le1,0\le y\le1\}$$which I thought that I might be able to solve. Here is my attempt at doing so:$$\begin{align}I=\int_Df(x,y)dxdy\implies&\;\iint_{[0,1]^2}(-1)^{\operatorname{Ln(xy)}}dxdy\\\implies&\;\iint_{[0,1]^2}(e^{i\pi})^{\operatorname{Ln}(x)+\operatorname{Ln}(y)}dxdy\end{align}$$and while we could use $(-1)^x=\cos(\pi x)+i\sin(\pi x)$, this would just end up more and more complicated to integrate as we went on. So now we have$$\int_0^1x^{i\pi}dx\int_0^1y^{i\pi}dy$$Now, we have$$-\left(\dfrac1{\pi^2-2i\pi-1}\right)(1-0)(1-0)$$$$=\dfrac{1-2i\pi-\pi^2}{\pi^4+2\pi^2+1}\approx-0.07507-0.05318i$$Therefore,$$\mathfrak{Re}\left(\iint_{[0,1]^2}(-1)^{\operatorname{Ln}(xy)}dxdy\right)\le\mathfrak{Re}\left(\int_0^1(-1)^{\ln(x)}dx\right)$$

---

Now, for a very quick reasoning on why I am doing the replacement $a^{bc}=(a^b)^c$ with complex numbers here:

---

We have that$$\mathfrak{Re}((-1)^x)=\cos(\pi x),\mathfrak{Im}((-1)^x)=i\sin(\pi x)$$and since we know$$\cos(ax)+i\sin(ax)=e^{iax}$$we have (in this case)$$x\mapsto\operatorname{Ln}(xy)\implies(-1)^{\operatorname{Ln}(xy)}=\cos(\pi\operatorname{Ln}(xy))+i\sin(\pi\operatorname{Ln}(xy))=(e^{i\pi})^{\operatorname{Ln}(xy)}$$$$\implies e^{i\pi\operatorname{Ln}(x)}e^{i\pi\operatorname{Ln}(y)}=x^{i\pi}y^{i\pi}$$And to justify raising $0$ to the $(1+i\pi)$th power, what I can say is that $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0}x^{1+i\pi}=0$

---

#### My question

---

Is it true that$$\mathfrak{Re}\left(\iint_{[0,1]^2}(-1)^{\operatorname{Ln}(xy)}dxdy\right)\le\mathfrak{Re}\left(\int_0^1(-1)^{\ln(x)}dx\right)$$or not and why?

Comment: The "area" makes this read oddly.  What is the "area" of an integral?

Comment: Integrals have values, not "areas". For a function from $\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$, the value of the integral is a measurement of an area. But only one of your two integrals fits that description. The value of the other is a measurement of the *volume* of a 3D region. If you want to compare the *values* of two integrals even though one is of an area and the other is of a volume, okay, but don't talk about the "area" of a volumetric integral.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the *definition* $$(-1)^t = e^{i\pi t}$$
it is clear enough that $$\iint_D (-1)^{\ln xy}dA = \left(\int_0^1 (-1)^{\ln t}dt\right)^2$$
using logic similar to what you have described. So it is just a matter of computing the right integral and comparing the real portions of it and its square.

We can start with a change of variables $u = -\ln t, t = e^{-u}$ to get $$\int_0^\infty e^{-i\pi u}e^{-u}\,du = \int_0^\infty e^{a u}\,du$$ where $a = -1 -i\pi$. This integral is $$\left.\frac1a e^{au}\right|_0^\infty = \frac1a(0-1)=\frac1{1+i\pi} = \frac{1-i\pi}{\pi^2+1}$$
and $$\left(\frac{1-i\pi}{\pi^2+1}\right)^2 = \frac{1-\pi^2 -i2\pi}{(\pi^2+1)^2}$$
Since the real part of the single integral is positive, while the real part of its square is negative, your claim is true.